# How to format a language tree?

Tags: xetex, tikz-qtree, forest

I would like to format the a language tree with XeLaTeX.

The question is how to balance it so that it fits within the page width.

### Monospaced font

In a mono-spaced font it looks like indicated below. It fits into the page width.

````
 Table 1: The Bassari language in the Niger-Congo Family

```
                                                Niger-Congo
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                               Atlantic-Congo
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                                Volta-Congo
                                                     |
                                                     |
       ...................................................................................
       |               |                   |                  |                          |
                   |
      Kru         (New) Kwa       (New) Benue-Congo      Dogon(?)              North Volta-Congo
                                                                                         |

                                                                   .......................

                                                                   |                     |

                                                         (Central) Gur             Adamawa-Ubangi

                                                                   |
                                                                   |
                                                                   |

                            ........................................................
                            |                                                      |
                          North                                                  South
                            |                                                      |
                            |                                                      |
         ....................................     ...........................................
         |              |                   |     |               |
     Oti-Volta        Bwamu             Kurumfe      Grunsi       Kirma/Tyurama      Dyan (etc.)
     ---------
         |
         |
         ....................................................................................
           |                  |                  |                        |                 |
     Buli/Konni            Eastern           Western                   Gurma            Yom/Naudem
                                                                       -----
                                                                         |
                                                                         |
             ...........................................................................................
             |               |                   |                    |         |                      |
     Ncham/Bassari    Akasele/Chamba   Konkomba, many dialects  Gangam/Dye    Gurma     Moba(Moore Gurma, Bimoba)
```

````

### 2. LaTeX code

A complete XeLaTeX file

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{lipsum} %This package just generates Lorem Ipsum filler text. 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}



\begin{document}

\section*{Language tree Ntcham}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent     path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.Niger-Congo
[.Atlantic-Congo
[.Volta-Congo
                    [.Kru ]
                    [.North 
                       [.Gur
                          [.Senufo ] 
                          [.Central 
                            [.North
                              [.Bwamu ]
                              [.Kurumfe ]
                              [.Oti-Volta 
                                 [.Buli/Konni ] [.Eastern ] [.Western     ]                       
                                 [.Gurma
                                    [.Ntcham/Bassari ]
                                    [.Akasele/Chamba ] 
                                    [.Konkomba, many dialects ]
                                    [.Gangam/Dye ]
                                    [.Gurma ]    
                                    [.Moba(Moore Gurma, Bimoba) ]
                                 ]
                                 [.Yom/Naudem ]
                               ]
                              ]
                            ]
                            [.South [.Grusi ] [.Kirma/Tyurama ] [.Dyan    (etc.) ]
                        ]
                      ]  
                   ]
                   [.Adamawa-Ubangi ]
               ]
               [.Kwa ] 
          ]
   ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}


\section*{Description}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

### 3. Formatted

Tree is too wide

[image: PDF view of formatted XeLaTeX code]

### 4. Question

Packages used are

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
```

1. Is this the right combination?
2. How can I used this packages to shift branches of the tree so that the whole tree fits?

Comment: TikZ loads `graphicx` automatically. Hence anything that loads TikZ will load `graphicx` anyhow. Here both loads TikZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shrink it down as I do on page 1, but I don't recommend it because of legibility.  But on page 2, I present it as a `sidewaysfigure` and that seems more reasonable (it ends up as 1.05 times the size of `\small`).

EDITED so to squeeze table entries with the use of `\sq{}` for left-or-right end entries off by themselves (like Kru, Senufo, Yom/Naudem, Adamawa-Ubangi, and Kwa), `\sql{}` for entries on the left side of a crowded line (like Bwamu, Buli/Konni, Ntcham/Bassari, and Grussi), and `\sqr{}` for entries on the right side of a crowded line (like Moba(...), Dyan, and (etc.)).  By using these macros, I was able to rescale the tree approximately 66% larger than in its natural state, to a scale of 1.05 times the size of `\small` when using the `sidewaysfigure`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{lipsum} %This package just generates Lorem Ipsum filler text. 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newsavebox\mytree
\newcommand\sq[1]{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}
\newcommand\sql[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\makebox[.2\wd0][r]{#1}}
\newcommand\sqr[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\makebox[.2\wd0][l]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\section*{Language tree Ntcham}

\savebox\mytree{%
{\small\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent     path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.Niger-Congo
[.Atlantic-Congo
[.Volta-Congo
                    [.\sq{Kru} ]
                    [.North 
                       [.Gur
                          [.\sq{Senufo} ] 
                          [.Central 
                            [.North
                              [.\sql{Bwamu} ]
                              [.Kurumfe ]
                              [.Oti-Volta 
                                 [.\sql{Buli/Konni} ] [.Eastern ] [.Western     ]                       
                                 [.Gurma
                                    [.\sql{Ntcham/Bassari} ]
                                    [.Akasele/Chamba ] 
                                    [.Konkomba, many dialects ]
                                    [.Gangam/Dye ]
                                    [.Gurma ]    
                                    [.\sqr{Moba(Moore~Gurma,~Bimoba)} ]
                                 ]
                                 [.\sq{Yom/Naudem} ]
                               ]
                              ]
                            ]
                            [.South [.\sql{Grusi} ] [.Kirma/Tyurama ] [.\sqr{Dyan}    \sqr{(etc.)} ]
                        ]
                      ]  
                   ]
                   [.\sq{Adamawa-Ubangi} ]
               ]
               [.\sq{Kwa} ] 
          ]
   ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\scalebox{.68}{\usebox{\mytree}}

\section*{Description}
\lipsum[3]
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\scalebox{1.05}{\usebox{\mytree}}
\caption{Language tree Ntcham}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the inline version on p.1, which is 68% the size of `\small`:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You're right to load the `forest` package, because that is designed for making horizontally compact trees. But you didn't actually *use* it in your MWE — your tree was made using `tikz-qtree`.

So, I used `forest` to modify your MWE and produce the following output. I also added `align=center`, which allows you to put line breaks within nodes using `\\`, saving a lot of horizontal space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %This package just generates Lorem Ipsum filler text. 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margin lines; comment this package out for the final version

\begin{document}

\section*{Language tree Ntcham}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path [thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-7pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }, % this option together with setting the parent and child anchors to south and north, respectively, gives you the right-angle style for your branches
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    align=center, % allows you to put line breaks within nodes
}
[Niger-Congo
    [Atlantic-Congo
        [Volta-Congo
            [(New)\\Kru]
            [(New)\\Kwa]
            [Benue-Congo]
            [Dogon(?)]
            [North
                [Gur
                    [Senufo]
                    [Central
                        [North
                            [Bwamu]
                            [Kurumfe]
                            [Oti-Volta 
                                [Buli/Konni]
                                [Eastern]
                                [Western]
                                [Gurma
                                    [Ntcham/\\Bassari]
                                    [Akasele/\\Chamba] 
                                    [{Konkomba,\\many dialects}]
                                    [Gangam/\\Dye]
                                    [Gurma]    
                                    [{Moba\\(Moore Gurma,\\Bimoba)}]
                                ]
                                [Yom/Naudem]
                            ]
                        ]
                        [South
                            [Grusi]
                            [Kirma/Tyurama]
                            [Dyan]
                            [etc.]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            [Adamawa-Ubangi]
            ]
        ]
    ]   
]
\end{forest}


\section*{Description}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note: I followed your monospaced version of the tree rather than the MWE; it looked to me (I'm a Bantuist) like the MWE version had Kru too low and South Gur too high. I did keep Senufo as a sister of Central Gur, which was in the MWE but not the monospaced version.)

I was able to keep your tree within the margins just by using `forest` and adding line breaks within nodes, but here are some other methods you could use for future trees if they need to be bigger:

- **Adjust the order of branches.** Sometimes it helps to move sisters around. For example, you can make this tree even more compact by moving Oti-Volta to the left of Kurumfe.
- **Scale the whole tree down.** I would recommend using `\scalebox` to do this. For example, you could put in `\scalebox{0.7}{put your tree here}` to scale the tree down by 30%. (This is a `graphicx` command; `graphicx` is loaded by `tikz`, which is loaded by `forest` and `tikz-qtree`, so if you're using `forest` or `tikz-qtree`, you don't have to load `graphicx` separately.)
- **Rotate the tree 90 degrees.** I would recommend using the `rotating` package to do this.