# qtree spacing and alignment

Tags: trees, qtree

I have the following qtree

```
\begin{center}                                      

\Tree[.{\tiny \ttfamily \itseries educated at}{\tiny \ttfamily ( Bush, University of Texas at Austin)}  [. [. \textit{\tiny 193938.xml} ]
    [. \textit{\tiny sentence 2} ]]
    [. [. [. [. \textit{\tiny Q Value} \textit{\tiny University of Texas at Austin} ]
    [. [.\textit{\tiny Q Value} ]\textit{\tiny Bush} ] ] ][. [. [. [. \textit{\tiny P26} \textit{\tiny educated at} ]]]]]]

\end{center}
```

The alignment is really messing up my paper.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

as you can see, it just sort of trails off into the margin there.

How can I fix that?

I guess it could be easily done if I could just move the center branch furthur up so that the one on the right didn't jut out as far.

[This is the complete project](https://github.com/h1395010/latex_tree)

**UPDATE**

```
\begin{forest}
[{\tiny \ttfamily \itseries educated at}{\tiny \ttfamily ( Bush, University of Texas at Austin)}, qtree edges,s sep=1cm [[\ts{.}] [[[$\epsilon$]]
```

[$\epsilon$]]][[$\epsilon$]]]
    \end{forest}

:/ How to use forest?

I hope it can look like this:

[image]

Comment: By the way, don't just provide a code snippet, but a MWE, possibly complete with text (even Lipsum would be fine) so we can test it without having to write the whole code from scratch.

Comment: [here is a link to the full files](https://github.com/h1395010/latex_tree)

Comment: [Is this how it's supposed to appear?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lu5zl.png)

Comment: sort of, but it's a document with two collumns of text, like [this one](http://turing.cs.washington.edu/papers/cikm07.pdf), so i was hoping to fit it into a single collum, d'you know I mean?

Comment: The code you provided in the comments doesn't have a two-column layout. That's why I asked for a MWE in your question: I'm spending more time figuring out your code than the problem. :)

Comment: ah, yikes. I'm sorry for that. [this is the template](http://acl2015.org/call_for_papers.html) I was using. I don't know what is an AWT. I always just use sharelatex.com

Comment: The screenshot of your document you provided in your question: where is the code that you compiled to get that? The one in Github is not it.

Comment: Once you figure out how to use `forest` (and there are many, many examples on this site if you search for forest or filter using its tag), if the tree still doesn't fit horizontally, here are some questions/answers that give options for making it fit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225355/42880, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230474/42880, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226435/42880.

Comment: its [this](http://acl2015.org/files/acl2015.tex), and [this](http://acl2015.org/files/acl2015.sty) and [this](http://acl2015.org/files/acl.bst), and that table in the OP plus `\usepackage{qtree}` that. that tree and package thing go in the `.tex` file

Answer (score 2):

Use the `forest` package. It's much better than `qtree`. And it's meant to deal precisely with proper alignment.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with latex. please forgive me but is it possible that you might show me how it could be adapted to the tree I created with qtree?

Comment: It is possible but give it a go first for your education.  Run `texdoc forest` and take a quick look at page 5. Example number 3 is quite similar to yours.

Comment: i tried to give it a shot, but it's kind of confusing. i put my failed attempt up there in the OP under **update** as well as a drawing of what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `forest` solution to get you started.

If you run into a divide by 0 error, you will need to tweak the value of `outer ysep` in the definition of the `nice trees` style; this is a workaround from the comments on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204094/42880) about a bug that causes this error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    nice trees/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      base=top,
      inner sep=1pt,
      l-=4ex,
      before typesetting nodes={
          if content={}{
            for parent={
              for children={anchor=north},
              calign=fixed edge angles,
              calign angle=60,              
            },
            inner sep=0pt,
            outer ysep=-0.49pt,
            calign=fixed edge angles,
            calign angle=60,       
          }{},
      },
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
nice trees
[\textsc{Data Representation}\\{\textit{educated at}(Bush, UT Austin)}
    [
        [filename]      
        [sentence \# ]
    ]
    [
        [
            [
                [$Q$ value]
                [English]
            ]
            [
                [$Q$ value]
                [English]
            ]
        ]
        [
            [$P$ value]
            [English]
        ]
    ]
]  
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the tree still doesn't fit horizontally after implementing `forest`, here are some questions/answers that give several ideas of ways to make it fit: [Margins and positioning with tikz-dependency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230474/42880), [How to format a language tree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225355/42880), [Reducing forest tree width without squashing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226435/42880).

I don't know if you actually want "Data Representation" as part of the top node of the tree, but at least it shows you how you can use `\\` to split nodes into multiple lines (this is allowed because of `align=center` in the `nice trees` style).

Comment: ah! amazing! I made the text to `\tiny` and theres a small bit of protrusion into the margin, but, i'll check out those resources and try to get it all lined up.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English, the first things you should try would be to split long nodes onto multiple lines and to scale the whole tree down using `\scalebox`. See the links I provided at the end of the answer for further explanation. You might want to reduce the font size to `\footnotesize`, but there's rarely need to take it all the way down to `\tiny`.

Comment: I just `\begin{center}`ed it and that did the trick :)